# Vertical alignment of \underset

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, amssymb

I have an equation like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

My equation is $X \overset{A}{\underset{B}{\rightleftarrows}} Y$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

but it's really bugging me that there's so much space in between the arrows and the 'B', especially since there's about the right amount of space between the arrows and the 'A'.

Is there a straightforward way to typeset this equation that avoids this issue? I tried putting the 'B' inside a \raisebox, but it appeared to have no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I've edited this answer to mention the `\overunderset` macro, which has the same issue as a nested combination of `\overset` and `\underset`.)

It would appear that `\rightleftarrows` is programmed to think of itself as having a component that protrudes *below* the baseline. This can be addressed by applying `\smash[b]` to `\rightleftarrows`.

If you have several such cases in a document, it may be worth your time to define a macro called, say, `\myunderset`, which applies `\smash[b]` automatically to its second argument.

The OP's issue also applies to `\overunderset`, which (unsurprisingly) combines the actions of `\overset` and `\underset`. Again, defining a variant macro called, say, `\myoverunderset`, that applies `\smash[b]` to the third argument, can be of help.

Please note that I'm *not* advocating the indiscriminate use `\myunderset` and `\myoverunderset`. Please apply them only in cases such as `\rightleftarrows`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \overset, \underset, \overunderset, and \smash[b] macros
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \rightleftarrows macro
\newcommand\myunderset[2]{\underset{#1}{\smash[b]{#2}}}
\newcommand\myoverunderset[3]{\overunderset{#1}{#2}{\smash[b]{#3}}}

\begin{document}
$X \overset{A}{\underset{B}{\rightleftarrows}} Y$ vs.\ 
$X \overunderset{A}{B}{\rightleftarrows} Y$ vs.\
$X \overset{A}{\underset{B}{\smash[b]{\rightleftarrows}}} Y$ vs.\
$X \overset{A}{\myunderset{B}{\rightleftarrows}} Y$ vs.\
$X \myoverunderset{A}{B}{\rightleftarrows} Y$
\end{document}
```